# XAMPP - I can connect to external ip, but others can't?

Tags: apache-http-server, xampp

I have XAMPP installed on windows machine and I have completed my website. Basically I have configured apache things, opened up port:80, made sure that my external ip is correct, disabled firewall in router and on server. Now when I enter my external ip on my browser I connect to my website and same thing with my domain name too, but when someone else tries to connect through my IP or domain name, then it fails to connect to server. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your port forwarding is correct, a possible issue could be your ISP blocking port 80, you could test this by changing port forward to another port such as 8080 and testing with that port.